# PSR500/Pro106/WS1040 Phase II Upgrade?

Tags: receiver, diy, equipment-design

I want to know if one can upgrade the hardware chips/ the CPU/DSP inside police scanners to do Phase II.

I know they cannot do Phase II due to hardware/software limits but if whistler can upgrade these other legacy scanners from RS and GRE to do DMR/NXDN and Phase II they can do it with this as well.

There has to be a way.

Whistler has chosen NOT to upgrade these models.  Now the PSR800 uses a DSP CPU combo of part numbers

https://wiki.radioreference.com/index.php/PSR-800

CPU:

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/renesas-electronics-america/M30626FHPGP-U5C/M30626FHPGP-U5C-ND/964955

DSP:

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TMS320VC5507PGE/296-17287-ND/680421

Will these parts FIT into the Pro 106?  Are the pinouts the same?  What about the Reneasas flash loader?  What about any other AMBE chip?

https://i.ytimg.com/vi/EASmyA6F29s/maxresdefault.jpg

The TGID displayed is a Phase I only.

Now I have used google, I have used that easier to read manual for all those radios, I have asked RR and Youtube and various HAMs.

I am not looking to do SDR at this time. I know all about TP4 and Tapping.

The programming in the radio is python based I think.

Comment: Hello Charles, and welcome to this site! Please consider taking [the tour](http://ham.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help pages](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help) to get the most from the site.

Comment: Also, regarding what @MarcusMüller removed, it's against our [code of conduct](https://ham.stackexchange.com/conduct) for anyone to tell you "Did you Google this?!" --or any other unkind behavior that is common on other sites-- and one of us would step in and resolve that. [Scroll down there](https://ham.stackexchange.com/conduct) to *Unacceptable behavior* and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

> if whistler can upgrade these other legacy scanners from RS and GRE to do DMR/NXDN and Phase II they can do it with this as well.

Says someone with technical insight into the engineering of these radios?

> There has to be a way.

That's unfounded wishful thinking.

Generally, exchanging the CPU and DSP in any board pretty much means a redesign of at least the software. So, if you have access to the source code of the software they run on that device, extensive knowledge in PCB rework (doesn't sound like it), and access to their development tools, maybe that's possible. I can't tell.

Since you have none of that, an "upgrade" will be impossible. (I'm having a hard time calling this an upgrade; what you're describing is mainly a replacement keeping a few parts of the radio.)